# Excel VBA - range offset

Tags: excel, vba, insert, offset, beforeupdate

I'm trying to make a code which after insert/update value in one cell, will go to the next cell like on the picture. Now this code works only one way:

`ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select` ex. from `A2 to B2`.

What to do to return offset to the cell on the left from `B2 to A3` - need loop like on the picture.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood what you are looking!
I set a range on column A and B until row 10, just for testing.

This code moves to the next cell on the picture whenever you edit
the cell and then you press Enter.

**Put this code on the sheet module**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngColA As Range: Set rngColA = Range("A2:A10")
    Dim rngColB As Range: Set rngColB = Range("B2:B10")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngColA) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        exit sub
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngColB) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(1, -1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: YES - that is what I need. Thanks a lot @Elio Fernandes